# Trying to install 32-bit packages to 64-bit AMD machine, their dependencies break the 64-bit versions

Tags: 64-bit, amd-processor

I'm trying to get a game running after the 14.10 update broke it.  It's a 32-bit game which I'm trying to play on my AMD 64-bit machine.  I'm supposed to install these packages:

```
libgtk2.0-0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libsdl-image1.2:i386 libsdl-sound1.2:i386 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386
```

Turns out they've got dependencies.  After adding them and then adding the dependencies that the dependencies wants, I've ended up with these to add.

```
libgtk2.0-0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libsdl-image1.2:i386 libsdl-sound1.2:i386 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386 libmikmod3:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libpulse0:i386  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libjson-c2:i386 libllvm3.5:i386 libqt5feedback5  libedit2:i386 unity-webapps-qml libcheese7 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl20 gstreamer1.0-clutter libedit2 libjson-c2 libasound2-plugins signon-ui-x11 ubuntu-html5-container liboxideqt-qmlplugin unity8-common
```

But some of those break the 64-bit versions of themselves.

```
libedit2 : Breaks: libedit2:i386 (!= 3.1-20140620-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+4) but 3.1-20140620-1 is to be installed
libedit2:i386 : Breaks: libedit2 (!= 3.1-20140620-1) but 3.1-20140620-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+4 is to be installed
libjson-c2 : Breaks: libjson-c2:i386 (!= 0.11-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) but 0.11-4ubuntu1 is to be installed
libjson-c2:i386 : Breaks: libjson-c2 (!= 0.11-4ubuntu1) but 0.11-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the version numbers, you've used some repo named `deb.sury.org` or something similar, but are no longer using that repo. If you downgrade `libedit2` and `libjson-c2` to the versions in the default repo, then everything will work.

To do that, run `sudo apt-get install libedit2=3.1-20140620-1 libjson-c2=0.11-4ubuntu1`.

Comment: Thank you!  Two questions, to better help me understand what's going on: why did that cause conflicts between the 32-bit and the 64-bit versions, and how did you recognize the problem?

Comment: The underlying architecture ([Multiarch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec)) requires that the 32-bit and 64-bit (and any other architecture, I suppose) have the same version of the library installed. In this case, it was obvious that there was a version mismatch since the `amd64` and the `i386` versions both complained of a breakage, and the to-be-installed version and the expected version were "diagonally" equal.